# Spark: how to parse empty string values as null in json

Tags: json, apache-spark

I have data that looks like this:

```
{"domain_userid":"a","g_id":"1"}
{"domain_userid":"b"}
{"domain_userid":"c","g_id":""}
```

I'm loading this into a DataFrame with

```
spark.read.schema(myschema).json("/my/json")
```

This results in a DataFrame like this:

```
+--------------------+--------+
|       domain_userid|g_id    |
+--------------------+--------+
|a                   | 1      |
|b                   | null   |
|c                   |        |
```

What I'm looking for is

```
+--------------------+--------+
|       domain_userid|g_id    |
+--------------------+--------+
|a                   | 1      |
|b                   |    null|
|c                   |    null|
```

I know I could write a udf to map empty strings to null, but my data has many columns (100+) so this seems like there could be a performance penalty because many tranformations are involved. Is there any flag/option on the json parser to just write null from the start?

Comment: You can use `regexp_replace` instead of UDF

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the CSV reader has such an option:

```
nullValue (default empty string): sets the string representation of a null value
```

However, the json reader has not implemented this option. (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#json-org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset-)

Answer (score 0):

json file:

```
{"domain_userid":"","g_id":"1"}
{"domain_userid":"b"}
{"domain_userid":"c","g_id":""}
```

try this:

```
df = spark.read.load('file:///home/zht/PycharmProjects/test/json_file.json', format='json')

myfunc = f.UserDefinedFunction(lambda *args: map(lambda x: None if x == '' else x, args),
                               returnType=ArrayType(StringType()))
cols = df.columns
df = df.select(myfunc(*cols)).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)
df = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema=cols)
df.show()
```

and output:

```
+-------------+----+
|domain_userid|g_id|
+-------------+----+
|         null|   1|
|            b|null|
|            c|null|
+-------------+----+
```

Comment: This will work, but it does not answer my question. I asked if there exists a parsing flag/option for treating empty strings as null, so I can solve this without writing a UDF. Also, this solution assumes that all my columns are of StringType, which is not the case (I parse using schema). So you should use df.dtypes instead of df.columns